# Java:How to Randomly Change Background And Font Color

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

If you touch the screen, I wish the background color and font color were changed together.

I want to change the font and background into a single set and change it to a specified unique color.

It is not difficult to change them separately, but I am not sure how to change the font and background color at the same time.

Waiting for your help.
I want to say thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change it randomly you can use this one

```
 private void changeColors () {
        switch (new Random().nextInt([Number Of options])) {
            case 0:
                textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
                layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
            case 1:
                textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
                layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
            case 2:
                textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
                layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
            case 3:
                textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
                layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
            case 4:
                textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
                layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
            case 5:
                textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
                layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
        }

    }
```

If you want to set them in an order you could use this, setting a counter in the on-click listener defining an n outside of it;

```
n=0;

view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        changeColors(n);
        n + 1;
    }
});

private void changeColors () {
    switch (n) {
        case 0:
            textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
            layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
        case 1:
            textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
            layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
        case 2:
            textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
            layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
        case 3:
            textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
            layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
        case 4:
            textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
            layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
        case 5:
            textView.setTextColor([COLOR]);
            layout.setBackgroundColor([COLOR]);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the code value that actually applies?

Comment: textView.setTextColor([COLOR]); = textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")); I solved it like this.

Comment: nextInt([Number Of options])) = I don't know this.

Comment: Just add an int there, that would be the maximum number of options of colors that you have un the switch

Comment: In this example, is it 5? nextInt([5])) {

Comment: I was very happy about changing the color. However, the color changes randomly once and does not change to another color even if you click again. Am I missing something?

Comment: textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                changeColors();

Comment: I set it to change when I click the text view

Comment: Solved with (break;)!!! Thank you so much. I solved it thanks to you!!!!!!! Thank you, thank you!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome, sorry for not answering fast but I was sleeping haha, It would help a lot if you upvote my answer

Comment: Yes I did! If you know the answer to this question, I hope you give me a hint! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65911688/i-would-like-to-know-how-to-put-an-image-in-the-calendar-view?noredirect=1#comment116537847_65911688")

Answer (score 0):

Set on onClickListener for whatever you want to be clicked in order for the colors to change (you could create a view that height and width is match_parent, and overlay it over other elements:

```
view.setOnClickListener(v - > {
    //Text
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    //Background
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.different_color_background);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two thing.

1. `onCLickListener`.
2. `onTouchListener`.

`onClickListener` works when you click on a `thing`/`view`. `onTouchListener` works when you touch or, hover the `thing`/`view`.

I am going to give you both example.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Text
            textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            //Background
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.different_color_background);
        }
    });
    


view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Text
            textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            //Background
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.different_color_background);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But, your title is saying to change background randomly. So, you have to create an array(drawable array/drawable list). You can take color array or color list. Then,

```
// create instance of Random class 
    Random rand = new Random(); 

    // Generate random integers in range 0 to 999 
    int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(list.length);
```

take random number. Show that color instead of `color` or `image resource`